# How to set in iPhone the same vertical position in Visual Format Language (VFL)?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout

How to set in iPhone the same vertical position in Visual Format Language (VFL)?

I need do the layout above for my ecommerce app:

[image: ECOMMERCE]
I just got the TITLE 1, TITLE 2 and PLUS BUTTON with correct position with the code:

```
let viewsDictionary1 = ["title1": title1!, "title2": title2!, "plusButton": plusButton!]
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[title1]-[title2]-[plusButton]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary1))

let viewsDictionary2 = ["title1": title1!]
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[title1]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary2))

let viewsDictionary3 = ["title2": title2!]
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[title2]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary3))

let viewsDictionary4 = ["plusButton": plusButton!]
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[plusButton]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary4))
```

But how i put on right side of PLUS BUTTON, the QUANTITY label, the MINUS BUTTON and the TOTAL label?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would suggest you look at this library https://github.com/abdullah-chhatra/iLayout for easy handling of constraints.

Comment: "H:|-[plushButton]-[counter]-[minusButton]-|" try this as last constraint.